# Self destructiong hard drives mystery

Tags: linux, hard-drive, arch-linux

What they all have in common:

- All mechanical disks
- Installed on arch-linux systems
- The computer is on 24/7
- All of them bought new from the store in the last three years
- All of them host ext4 partitions
- The partition table was made with fdisk
- All computers lay on the same place

What it happen's to many of them:

- They start to die after weeks or months for no reason.

Total number of victims:

- 4

Things that I changed:

- Hardware, totally different computers, same keyboard, mouse and case only
- Software, different installations of arch linux, same programs installed, share some users and groups

I know that a system being on non stop is a huge stress but most people have healthy disks at these conditions including me.

Possible causes:

- Arch linux is a serial hard drives killer ??
- Pc parts sellers on my city are all pricks
- Modern mechanical hard drives are made of cardboard
- I'm Magneto????

---

Edit:
For those who asked, here are some kernel messages through journal ctl:

```
Sep 27 22:59:05 archiso kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
Sep 27 22:59:05 archiso kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
Sep 27 22:59:05 archiso kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 3b d4 ad e8 00 00 10 00
Sep 27 22:59:05 archiso kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1003793896 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Sep 27 22:59:05 archiso kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#9 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=4s
Sep 27 22:59:05 archiso kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#9 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
Sep 27 22:59:05 archiso kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#9 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
Sep 27 22:59:05 archiso kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#9 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 5b d4 b2 30 00 00 08 00
Sep 27 22:59:05 archiso kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1540665904 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Sep 27 22:59:05 archiso kernel: ata2: EH complete
```

and here the result of smartctl -x

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.11.16-arch1-1] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate BarraCuda 3.5
Device Model:     ST1000DM010-2EP102
Serial Number:    ZN1R1X25
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0dbee2477
Firmware Version: CC46
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Sep 27 23:06:25 2021 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM level is:     128 (minimum power consumption without standby)
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
DSN feature is:   Unavailable
ATA Security is:  Disabled, NOT FROZEN [SEC1]
Wt Cache Reorder: Unavailable

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 116) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x1085) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR--   069   063   006    -    8617064
  3 Spin_Up_Time            PO----   099   097   000    -    0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--CK   100   100   020    -    343
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   100   100   010    -    0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         POSR--   061   060   045    -    1413579
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   099   099   000    -    930
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        PO--C-   100   100   097    -    0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   100   100   020    -    343
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
184 End-to-End_Error        -O--CK   100   100   099    -    0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
188 Command_Timeout         -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0 0 0
189 High_Fly_Writes         -O-RCK   100   100   000    -    0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel -O---K   067   063   040    -    33 (Min/Max 30/33)
193 Load_Cycle_Count        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    374
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   033   012   000    -    33 (0 12 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  -O-RC-   004   001   000    -    8617064
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O--C-   100   100   000    -    0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ----C-   100   100   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -OSRCK   200   200   000    -    0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       ------   100   253   000    -    659h+27m+34.555s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      ------   100   253   000    -    425240194
242 Total_LBAs_Read         ------   100   253   000    -    990859577
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O      5  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O      5  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x04       GPL,SL  R/O      8  Device Statistics log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  NCQ Command Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x21       GPL     R/O      1  Write stream error log
0x22       GPL     R/O      1  Read stream error log
0x24       GPL     R/O    512  Current Device Internal Status Data log
0x30       GPL,SL  R/O      9  IDENTIFY DEVICE data log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xa1       GPL,SL  VS      20  Device vendor specific log
0xa2       GPL     VS    4120  Device vendor specific log
0xa8       GPL,SL  VS     129  Device vendor specific log
0xa9       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xab       GPL     VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xb0       GPL     VS    4800  Device vendor specific log
0xbe-0xbf  GPL     VS   65535  Device vendor specific log
0xc0       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xc1       GPL,SL  VS      10  Device vendor specific log
0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (5 sectors)
No Errors Logged

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      00%       926         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       522 (0x020a)
Device State:                        Active (0)
Current Temperature:                    32 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     31/32 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     12/36 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0

SCT Data Table command not supported

SCT Error Recovery Control command not supported

Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04)
Page  Offset Size        Value Flags Description
0x01  =====  =               =  ===  == General Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x01  0x008  4             343  ---  Lifetime Power-On Resets
0x01  0x010  4             930  ---  Power-on Hours
0x01  0x018  6       426097940  ---  Logical Sectors Written
0x01  0x020  6         5275103  ---  Number of Write Commands
0x01  0x028  6      1111543100  ---  Logical Sectors Read
0x01  0x030  6         6138628  ---  Number of Read Commands
0x01  0x038  6               -  ---  Date and Time TimeStamp
0x03  =====  =               =  ===  == Rotating Media Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x03  0x008  4             929  ---  Spindle Motor Power-on Hours
0x03  0x010  4             303  ---  Head Flying Hours
0x03  0x018  4             374  ---  Head Load Events
0x03  0x020  4               0  ---  Number of Reallocated Logical Sectors
0x03  0x028  4               0  ---  Read Recovery Attempts
0x03  0x030  4               0  ---  Number of Mechanical Start Failures
0x03  0x038  4               0  ---  Number of Realloc. Candidate Logical Sectors
0x04  =====  =               =  ===  == General Errors Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x04  0x008  4               0  ---  Number of Reported Uncorrectable Errors
0x04  0x010  4               0  ---  Resets Between Cmd Acceptance and Completion
0x05  =====  =               =  ===  == Temperature Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x05  0x008  1              32  ---  Current Temperature
0x05  0x010  1              31  ---  Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x018  1               -  ---  Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x020  1              36  ---  Highest Temperature
0x05  0x028  1              20  ---  Lowest Temperature
0x05  0x030  1              31  ---  Highest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x038  1              27  ---  Lowest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x040  1               -  ---  Highest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x048  1               -  ---  Lowest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x050  4               0  ---  Time in Over-Temperature
0x05  0x058  1              55  ---  Specified Maximum Operating Temperature
0x05  0x060  4               0  ---  Time in Under-Temperature
0x05  0x068  1              13  ---  Specified Minimum Operating Temperature
                                |||_ C monitored condition met
                                ||__ D supports DSN
                                |___ N normalized value

Pending Defects log (GP Log 0x0c) not supported

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x000a  2            1  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
```

Comment: Is there some process continually, repeatedly, writing to the HDD? Use *iotop* or other utility to see what is eating the HDD's. Another, though unlikely, possibility: the PC's environment is damaging the drives, e.g., temperature, humidity, **very** high magnetic fields (near welders or tokamak), etc.

Comment: "Total number of victims: 4" – Out of how many? Out of 5 or out of 50?

Comment: In addition to what Dr. MP has said, also (a) much more development in good SSD drives, not so much in HDD drives and (b) be careful of buying "economy"drives

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski out of 6 or 8.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Nothing at all outside of usual, there's no custom daemon, nor exotic monitoring program, just the ones that come from default. I used iotop once, and fuser or some alike was eating my hdd while mantaining ext4 filesystem, It was journaling or something, it's probably not fuser but you know the application that maintains ext4, I think that was normal or if not it was just fighting against phisical corruption. I'm sure there's not a welder in kms around, it could be temperature, though last smart test reported 35°C, what i think it's normal.

Comment: @John I'm suspecting that, that hdd's are getting everytime less quality.

Comment: Yes. Put another way, highly reliable hard drives (long mean time to failure) are expensive.

Comment: *"They start to die after weeks or months for no reason."* -- Too vague. What kind of failure?  Mechanical?  Electrical?  Four failures are not statistically significant.  Are you aware of early product failure?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathtub_curve  *"All computers lay on the same place"* -- This really means that all drives can experience the same fault-inducing condition(s), e.g. vibration, which tends to discredit your assertion on quality.  Your title is unproven.

Comment: @sawdust I wish I know but I'm not a forensics; there's just something wrong at or below the partition table. Luckly they're  not significant if not the amount of money spent for nothing would be like so, hopefully this one is still under warranty.

Comment: It sounds like you've replaced all hardware except for a few peripherals. I've had issues with a bad SATA controller "kill" hard drives before. They weren't actually dead but the SATA controller just made them act up. You stated the computer is in the same spot for all builds. Have you verified the outlet you're plugging into isn't the problem? Have you tried a different outlet? I don't know if a faulty ground or other outlet problems would cause these issues.

Comment: You claim that you have 4 drives that are *"self-destructiong"* [sic] and *"start to die after weeks or months"*.  Now you post one SMART report for a drive that has 930 power-on hours (or 39 days?) and has SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: ***PASSED***.  What about the other three *"dying"* drives?  *"there's just something wrong at or below the partition table"* -- You need to refrain from telling us what you think is the cause, because you're writing nonsense.

Comment: @sawdust, sorry for nonsense ¿Where does it says PASSED? I haven't seen that. Anyway I forgot about this because the last issue

Comment: @sawdust, sorry for nonsense ¿Where does it says PASSED? I haven't seen that. Anyway I forgot about this because the last issue involving the 39 days old is apparently SOLVED. It resuted to be a MISALIGNED SATA CONNECTOR. I checked that connector many times to be tight but  only by repluging it soved the issue. It could be also the same problem with the other disks had happenned though there's still one that has a bad sector no matter how well I plug it. I'm sorry for this but I'm not totally used to sata drives and may be the old ide ones were more reliable.

Comment: `=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a misaligned sata power plug and may be it was all the times. The plug was tight but the angle was slightly wrong. This doesn't happen with good old moloks.

Comment: *"This doesn't happen with good old moloks."* -- Molex only made the power connectors.  IDE connectors are IDC (insulation displacement connector) and available from a variety of manufacturers.